# How do I temporarily take all CRM Online users offline?

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I need to prevent all CRM Online users from logging in for a short period time while I perform an upgrade to some of the customizations.

Disabling each user is time consuming and I believe that disabling will require a new "invitation" after the user is re-enabled.

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: How so? is it too administrative? I thought i may have to code something to do this.  You may be right.  I can move it elsewhere

Comment: yes. im sure theres a switch somewhere.

Comment: Help to create 'elsewhere': http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32455/microsoft-dynamics?referrer=jHf4j_VcIgLKPEy52a9q2g2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest trying to disable the Business Unit.  But you cannot do this if you only have one Business Unit defined.

http://rc.crm.dynamics.com/rc/2011/en-us/online/5.0/Help/source_set_BU_EnableDisable.htm

According to the online documentation above, disabling the BU will disable login for all users.
We would have to deduce a suitable methodology for managing this, for instance having a single user in a second “administrative” BU that you would login as that user to manage this process.

Comment: i'm going to try this and get back to you.

Comment: @GlennFerrieLive Did you ever try this? I need a way to disable access for certain users outside of certain hours and this sounds promising...